# How to reset bootstrap form-label or col-form-label's font size without overriding?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 5.1 and want to change the form-label and col-form-label default font-size. If I add something like below, it overrides .col-form-${size}-label. So, I couldn't go in this way. Is there a way to change the font-size?

```
.form-label, .col-form-label {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an extra class to that element then set the CSS like this:

```
.extraclass.form-label, .extraclass.col-form-label {
    font-size: 1rem;
}
```

With that, the `font-size` will be changed only for that element, not for all the elements with classes `form-label` or `col-form-label`.

Comment: The problem with this solution is, form-label and col-form-label is the default version of label. So I have to add "extraclass" to all of the default labels. It would be the default with a "extraclass"

Comment: I thought you want to change the size only for a specific element, If I understand well now, you want to change the size for all the old elements, but you don't want to override for the future elements.